# $\int x^x\frac { { (x }^{ 2x }+1)[\ln { (x)+1 } ] }{ { x }^{ 4x }+1 } dx$

Tags: integration

Can someone suggest me a method for integrating $\int  x^x\frac { { (x }^{ 2x }+1)[\ln { (x)+1 } ] }{ { x }^{ 4x }+1 } dx$ ?

I just need some hints.I've trying this for a long time.Which part of the expression should I substitute?

Comment: Could it be $(\ln(x)+1)$  instead of $\ln(x+1)$?

Comment: So you are looking for a substitution method...does that mean this is a cal 1 question? And if so is that one factor (ln(x)+1) or ln(x+1) ? That is is this $\int  x^x\frac { { (x }^{ 2x }+1)(\ln { (x)+1) }  }{ { x }^{ 4x }+1 } dx$ And if so I would begin with $u=x^x$

Comment: @randomgirl corrected the typo :-P

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm so sorry..i just missed the bracket

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm getting $\int \frac{u^2+1}{u^4+1}du$ since $ \frac{1}{u} du=(\ln(x)+1) dx$.

Comment: Yes, I messed up, will delete the comment. Then it is a subtler trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this if I have't gotten ahead of myself $\int \frac{1+\frac{1}{u^2}}{(u-\frac{1}{u})^2+2} du$ Then let $\sqrt{2}v=u-\frac{1}{u}$

Comment: In case you are wondering I first divided $\frac{u^2+1}{u^4+1}$ by $u^2$ on top and bottom. Then wrote $u^2+\frac{1}{u^2}$ as $u^2-2+\frac{1}{u^2}+2$ which can be written as $(u-\frac{1}{u})^2+2$.